# Will this finite state machine reject this number?

Tags: binary, finite-state-machine

I constructed the following acceptor $M_1$:

[image: State diagram]

Formal Definition:

$M_1=(Q,Σ,δ,q_1,F)$
$Q = \{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$
$Σ = \{0,1\}$
$δ = $ (see diagram)
$F = \{q_3\}$

$M_1$ processes a word $w = w_n…,w_3,w_2,w_1$ that consists of letters of the alphabet Σ. Simply stated, $M_1$ iterates over the (trailing) bits of a binary number from right to left. It accepts all numbers that contain at least one '0' and rejects the rest.

My question: will $M_1$ reject a binary number that consists of infinetly many ones $(11111111\dotsm)$? Or will the machine never halt and therefore deliver no result?

Comment: 1...11111111 can not represent an infinite sequence of ones as it pretends to have a last item whilst 'infinite' means having no last item.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that was just for illustration. How could I state it correctly?

Comment: You can say 'an infinite string/sequence 11111....'.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it in the description above. Originally I had tried to write it the other way around, since the machine iterates from right to left; however, this is not relevant for the definition of the infinite sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make sense to have an infinite input in a deterministic automaton. If you wish to have an infinite word as input, you have to use a richer model, called an [$\omega$-automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-automaton), which is a finite automaton with special acceptance conditions. I let you read the given link, since there are several variants of acceptance conditions.

Comment: Great advice, I think a Büchi automaton is what I need. Just out of curiosity: isn't that a deterministic machine as well?

Comment: There are deterministic and non deterministic Büchi automata. But contrary to the finite words case, they are not equivalent! I let you read the given Wikipedia link for more details.

Comment: Would it also be possible to model the algorithm with an Infinite Time Turing Machine?

Answer (score 0):

The machine will never halt as it halts when there is no more entry to process. It can’t be the case with this infinite entry.